# Are there computable reals that are not Dedekind-computable?

Tags: logic, computability

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) defines a **computable** real number to be a number where there exists an algorithm that can approximate it to within any *given* precision. I believe this definition is standard.

The Wikipedia article then claims, without giving a specific source:

> A real number is computable if and only if there is a computable Dedekind cut $D$ corresponding to it.

It is obvious that if the Dedekind cut for $\alpha$ is computable, then $\alpha$ is computable according to the first definition. The other direction sounds more iffy, though, and I've always been told it *doesn't* hold.

It is certainly not the case that given a Turing machine that approximates some $\alpha$ to within a given precision, we can *effectively derive* a Turing machine that decides its Dedekind cut. If we could do that, we could solve the halting problem by considering, for an arbitrary machine $M$, the number
$$ \alpha_M = \begin{cases} 1/m & \text{if $M$ halts in $m$ steps} \\ 0 & \text{if $M$ diverges} \end{cases} $$
It's easy to write down a concrete program that approximates $\alpha_M$ to any given precision. If we had an effective way to convert it to a Dedekind-cut decider, we could learn whether $M$ halts by asking the resulting machine whether $0 < \alpha_M$. (For this purpose I'm assuming Dedekind cuts where the *lower* set has no maximum; for the opposite convention consider $-\alpha_M$ instead).

However, this is not an example of a concrete number that *has* a machine of one type, but *doesn't* have one of the other type. No matter whether $M$ halts, $\alpha_M$ is even *rational*, so a machine that decides its Dedekind cut certainly *exists*, though we may never know which machine that is.

We can see, however, that even if Dedekind-cut deciding machines *exist* for all computable numbers, they are not something one can even begin to, ahem, *compute* with. It's easy to write programs that decide the cuts for $\sqrt2$ and $\alpha_M-\sqrt2$, so if we had an effective way to *add* cut-deciders, we could use it to discover whether $M$ halts.

This observation feels like a good reason not to use Dedekind cuts as a *definition* of computable reals. But it doesn't resolve the question of whether the pure (non-constructive) *existence* of a Dedekind-cut-deciding machine is equivalent to the (pure non-construtive) existence of an approximating machine.

Thus, my question: **Do we know whether there exist computable real numbers whose Dedekind cuts are not computable?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $x$ be a computable real number. If $x$ is rational, it is clearly a computable Dedekind cut number. Otherwise, let $f$ be the function which takes a positive rational $q$ and outputs rational $f(q)$ such that $|f(q) - x| < q$. Then we compute $D(r)$ as follows:

```
n ⟵ 1;
while true {
   if |r - f(1/n)| > 1/n then {
      return (r < f(1/n));
   } else {
         n ⟵ n + 1;
   }
}
```

It's easy to show that this always terminates, since $r \neq x$ and thus there exists $n$ such that $\frac{1}{2n} < |r - x|$. And it's easy to show that if it terminates, the algorithm is correct.

Comment: That was a lot simpler than I'd confused myself into expecting. :-)

Comment: You want $f(1/n)$ there, not $f(n)$.  And then better start with $n = 1$, not $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Correct. It is fixed.

Comment: It is worth noting that this proof is **not** constructive. If we are just given a code $f$, for some computable real $x$, we cannot construct a code for the Dedekind cut that defines $x$. I am guessing that this is why the OP was suspicious of the statement in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @RobArthan Correct. It is clear that there is no constructive proof that all computable numbers have a computable Dedekind cut. However, Markov's principle is all that is needed to show that there is no computable real number which does not have a computable Dedekind cut.